# How can one get a ResponsiveSlides slideshow to work in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am using ResponsiveSlides.js(http://responsive-slides.viljamis.com/) to display a slideshow on a website I'm working on. It works perfectly in Opera, Chrome, and Firefox, but IE displays the images much larger than they are supposed to be. Here is an example(http://www.brooklynlutheran.com/ie-maxwidth-test.asp). The demo code that ResponsiveSlides.js provides works OK, and I can't see any difference. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to communicate with the author of the slide show and see if there are known errors or if you are doing something wrong. You will get blasted here for asking a really generic question without providing code or markup for anyone to troubleshoot.

Comment: I don't like the max-width css property used. Maybe you could find a different solution since all other elements take up the entire area of that parent div, and only the slider is 400px, you could use width:400px not max-width. Maybe that helps.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard - he actually provided the code :) And the question isn't generic at all.

Answer (score 2):

Very likely max-width: 400px can be the problem because IE might not recognize it. I haven't done a research cause I am about to go home from work, but... put it like this:

```
<li><div style="width:400px;">[rest of code inside<li></li>]</div></li>
```

This might not autoresize the image inside it but at least it should limit. Then you might need some additional code to reduce them in size. Hope it helps. If by the time I come home noone else helps you, I will try to solve that and not only give the hint. Good luck :)

Edit:

```
<li id="rslides1_s0" style="display: none; float: none; position: absolute; " class=""><div style="width:400px;"><img src="./IE Maxwidth Test_files/test-pic1.jpg" alt=""></div></li>
```

Make the list items look like these (note the added ) do and it is fixed in IE :)

Comment: By the way: to answer your question "Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?" - I think the fault of this problem can be an oversight of the creators :) IE isn't very popular nowadays, which can lead to just not testing on it. Moreover CSS3 isn't still very stable and still can change in the future, so IE could just simply remove/change/not yet added max-width's property or it is named differently :)